# Phoenix (Elixir) Error running test suite

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have inherited a web project with a backend written in Elixir using the Phoenix framework. I am a Python (Django) developer by trade and new to Elixir. There is 0 test coverage on this project, so I thought that would be a good place to start and get familiar with Elixir and Phoenix. But I get an error message running `mix test` before I can even get started.

`16:27:35.818 [info] Application tzdata started at :nonode@nohost`

`** (Mix) Could not start application cowboy: exited in: :application.cowboy({:description, 'Small, fast, modular HTTP server.'}, {:vsn, '1.1.2'}, {:id, 'git'}, {:modules, [:cow_uri, :cowboy, :cowboy_app, :cowboy_bstr, :cowboy_clock, :cowboy_handler, :cowboy_http, :cowboy_http_handler, :cowboy_loop_handler, :cowboy_middleware, :cowboy_protocol, :cowboy_req, :cowboy_rest, :cowboy_router, :cowboy_spdy, :cowboy_static, :cowboy_sub_protocol, :cowboy_sup, :cowboy_websocket, :cowboy_websocket_handler]}, {:registered, [:cowboy_clock, :cowboy_sup]}, {:applications, [:kernel, :stdlib, :ranch, :cowlib, :crypto]}, {:mod, {:cowboy_app, []}}, {:env, []})`

`** (EXIT) :already_loaded`

And this is where, I am hoping, my ignorance of Elixir and Phoenix is hindering my debugging capability. Is this `tzdata` that is throwing this error and not letting the test suite load properly? Any direction or insight is appreciated.

*** UPDATE
This may be unsolvable. I am thankful for everyone's input. It helped to determine that this issue is a side-effect of some unique unconventionality of this application.

There are a lot of Supervisors getting called in a couple of the `application.ex` files which make it difficult to track down where it got sideways and began failing to work as a "conventional" Phoenix app does out of the box. By that I mean `mix phx.server` and `mix test` do not work as documented in the Phoenix documentation.

Comment: The `[info]` log might be a different log, I'm not sure it is related. `:cowboy` is the underlying HTTP server used by Phoenix, AFAIK it is not loaded directly but by the supervision tree defined in `<YourProject>.Application` starting `<YourProject>.Endpoint`. Is there any manual call to `Application.load/1` in your codebase?

Comment: Maybe an approach worth trying for debugging could be to generate a new empty phoenix project using the [generator](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Mix.Tasks.Phx.New.html) (try using the same version) and then compare what is being done in `Application`, `Endpoint`, `ConnCase`... might help spot something that seems off?

Comment: Don't worry about `[info] Application tzdata started at :nonode@nohost` -- the tzdata gets updated periodically so this is a common `info`

Does `mix phx.server` run?  Or does it blow up too?  It might be good to clear out the `_build` and `deps` directories, then re-install dependencies: `mix deps.get`
Just to make sure that you've got good versions on everything.

Comment: `mix phx.server` blows up, too. Lots of custom Supervisors in main umbrella app `application.ex` file seems to be the cause. Original dev wrote a custom Elixir app to run the server as a result. It has to have `mnesia` running and loaded with slug data before it can do anything, but it's not even used. Backend is pretty foo bar, so plan is to scrap it, if we can.

Comment: Could you put an example of your mix.exs file?

Comment: Is your phoenix app already started or the port 4000 has already been occupied? If you are on Linux, you can type `netstat -tlnp | grep 4000` to see if there's something listening on that port.

Comment: At the time we run `mix phx.serve` nothing else is running on that port. But its not specifically throwing a port in use exception. It's throwing an already loaded exception. Like a circular import in python. And it is do to custom logic in a couple of the `application.ex` files that are causing it. One of the first things I did was check ports and PIDs running already using netstat and htop.

Comment: This seems like a really custom setup -- if there are no docs as to how to get the thing started I would feel pretty frustrated with the previous developer.  
It sounds like you're up against a lack of documentation and custom surprises from the previous dev, but I wonder if you could find the bad process(es) by commenting out the children modules one by one in `application.ex` ... might be worth a shot.  If you could share your app/repo or relevant parts thereof, that might be the only practical way of debugging something like this.